# "If you get lonely, I hope you phone me" vs. "will phone me"

Tags: grammaticality, conditionals, present-tense

Which one is correct?

> - If you get lonely, I hope you **phone** me any time.
> - If you get lonely, I hope you **will phone** me any time.

A detailed explanation would be fantastic.

Comment: Please note that StackExchange expects posts to follow certain formatting rules, and this site in particular expects adhering to basic punctuation rules on top of that. New users are of course given some leeway, but are still expected to learn from other people's edits to their posts. And after as many as nine questions, it is probably not too much to ask that you start getting with the programme. So please take a minute to examine the edits made to your posts so far, and learn from them, so as to prevent additional work on the part of other community members in the future.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The first option, "If you get lonely, I hope you phone me any time," is what might be called pseudo-grammatically-correct: there is something terribly wrong with what comes after the comma, but it's difficult to pin the mistake down. As I said above, there are a dozen way of conveying the thought, but if someone is looking for a suggestion, mine, based on my guess as to what the writers' intention might be, is

If you get lonely, I'll always be there for you, just pick up the phone and call, anytime, night or day.

Comment: "There is a something wrong but I don't know what it is" is not a very useful answer.

Comment: For sure, but I can't think of an answer. Perhaps I should post the issue I raised as an independent question and see what other readers have to say—that might be an interesting experiment. In any event, my real objective was to show 18yoPolyglot that there was a completely different approach to his question, which I intuited as having more to do with communicating with someone than with grammar.

Comment: I just reread your reply and this time it jumped out of the page and bit me in the face.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation. Geoffrey

Answer (score 4):

Both are grammatical. To me the second (or rather, the contracted version *I hope you'll phone me*) is more natural.

However, neither of them is particularly natural for me, because I wouldn't combine *I hope* with *any time* (though I'm struggling to explain why).

So I would say:

> If you get lonely, I hope you'll phone me.

or

> If you get lonely, phone me any time.

but I'm not sure why your examples don't work for me.

Comment: *I hope you know that you can call me any time* sounds perfectly normal to me. I agree, though, that the best is your last example.

Comment: It looks unnatural because of the 'if' condition and the 'I hope' result. As it stands, the sentence is saying "you getting lonely will trigger me hoping you will call".

Comment: Roaring Fish: no, I don't think that's why. Agreed that the sentence _could_ have your interpretation, but pragmatically it doesn't: if it did, my first example above would fail in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

I've been scratching my head trying to pinpoint the problem with the sentence "If you get lonely, I hope you phone me any time" and now I think I've found it: "any time" was intended by the writer to be an adverbial modifier of "phone," but his syntax gets in the way. All that's needed is a comma to make the sentence more or less intelligible:

If you get lonely, I hope you phone me, anytime.

Things improve a little when the comma is replaced with a dash.

If you get lonely, I hope you phone me—anytime.

Comment: Yes, that version with the dash is better. A further improvement would be "...I hope **you'll** phone me..." (which, in the form "I hope **you will** phone me", was in fact one of the options presented by the OP).

Comment: Yes, of course. I was sticking to original sentence because I wanted to isolate the problem. See my answer below for the ultimate improvement.

Answer (score -1):

This is a classic case of grammar vs. style vs. usage vs. voice/mood. Grammar always gets the upper hand; then comes usage and style, and then voice/mood. In the example at hand, grammar is not an issue so let's look at usage and style. Even though the two sentences are ever-so simple, the first sentence is more formal; if we replace "lonely" with "have further questions", it might be appropriate for an e-mail reply from a help-center. Since the recipient is clearly a friend, consider, as already suggested above, dropping the "I hope you" and also consider "just give me a ring" instead "phone me." Or if you want a bit more formality, try "don't hesitate to call me." Note that these choices all have to do with interrelations of usage, style and voice. It shouldn't be difficult to invent a dozen other variants, each that would make a slightly different impression on the recipient, possibly influencing their opinion of the writer (his or her sincerity, intelligence, character, empathy, …) as they read. Conclusion: There is no answer to the question posed; everything depends on who is writing and who they are writing to, and what impression the writer wants to make.